# wazuh agent won't send file events unless restarted

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ossec

Have a wazuh (ossec fork) server and an agent (testing for now). the server gets all the info from the agent (login attempts and so on) but one thing - file changes (creation, deletion and so on). upon agent restarting, all the information is being sent.

I've made sure that *inotify* and *inotify-tools* are installed, even *build-essential* (just in case), but nothing. unless the agent is restarted, it will not send the new updates to the server.

OS ubuntu 16.04

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must take into account that the file change alerts are triggered when syscheckd detect any change from a previous scan, you can set the scan frequency using  option.

When an agent is started a file integrity scan start too if `<scan_on_start>yes</scan_on_start>` (enabled by default) is set, for that reason you receive alerts of file changes when you restart the agent.

Also, you could take a look to the `<realtime>` option, this will alert you when a file change instantly.

Here you can find the official documentation https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/reference/ossec-conf/syscheck.html

And our maillist is located at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wazuh we are glad to help you there too.

In addition, it could be nice you use the wazuh tag, we will appreciate that, thanks.

I hope this could help you.

Regards